# Editing value of third column based on other two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe with 4 columns , column 0 contains fruits names, column 1 contains no. of orders, column 2 contains customer name, column 4 contains day of delivery.

So If user change any value through a form it should reflect in csv file.

Here I used dataframe to manipulate csv file so column 0 and column 3 cannot be changed by user. So if user want to change number of orders and day of delivery, so to change their order they will enter their ordered fruit name and customer name and other two values which they want to change so it should reflect in csv file.

Here is the code:

```
0,0,1,2,3
0,Apple,3,customername_1,Monday
1,Apple,15,customername_2,Tuesday
2,Banana,15,customername_3,tuesday
3,Banana,3,customername_4,Wednesday
4,Watermelon,15,customername_5,Monday
5,Strawberry,15,customername_6,Thursday
```

```
value1 = "Apple"
value2 = "customer_1"
df = pd.read_csv("symbol.csv", index_col=False)
df.loc[((df["0"] == value1) & (df["2"] == value2)), "1"] = "5"
df.loc[((df["0"] == value1) & (df["2"] == value2)), "3"] = "Thursday"
df.to_csv("symbol.csv", index=False)
```

```
csv file I should get:
0,0,1,2,3
0,Apple,5,customer_1,Thursday
1,Apple,15,customername_2,Tuesday
2,Banana,15,customername_3,tuesday
3,Banana,3,customername_4,Wednesday
4,Watermelon,15,customername_5,Monday
5,Strawberry,15,customername_6,Thursday
```

I am not getting any result from my code.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to make your code reproducible and remove unnecessary bits to help answer your question.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([["Apple",3,"customer_1","Monday"],
                   ["Apple",15,"customer_2","Tuesday"],
                   ["Banana",15,"customer_3","Tuesday"]],
                  columns=['0','1','2','3'])

value1 = "Apple"
value2 = "customer_1"

df.loc[(df.loc[:,'0'] == value1) & (df.loc[:,'2'] == value2), '1'] = 5
df.loc[(df.loc[:,'0'] == value1) & (df.loc[:,'2'] == value2), '3'] = "Thursday"
```

Comment: thankyou for your answers but my column headings are of string type and this is not working for me.

Comment: I've modified the answer and column names are now of type string. If the solution answers your question, consider accepting it, thanks.